# Missing data recovery using tensor decomposition on Python Tensorly

Tags: python, tensor, tensorly

I'm trying to recovery missing data in a cluster trace like this:

[image]

I read some articles and find out I can create a tensor for this dataset, and then decompose the tensor to recover the missing data.

Now I'm using Tensorly, a tensor lib on python.I built a simple tensor like this:

```
import tensorly as tl
X = tl.tensor(np.arange(24).reshape((4, 6)))
X[0][5]= nan
X[1][5]= nan
```

and I got:

```
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,  nan],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  nan],
       [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.],
       [ 18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,  23.]])
```

and then I try to decompose it according to the official document:

```
from tensorly.decomposition import parafac
factors = parafac(X, rank=1)
print(tl.kruskal_to_tensor(factors))
```

I got all-nan result when the parameter rank is 1 or 2 or 3:

```
[[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

and error when when the parameter rank is bigger than 3:

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

How can I fix this? Any answer would help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that handling missing values is not supported in the current version of tensorly (https://github.com/tensorly/tensorly/issues/4 ).

See https://nipunbatra.github.io/blog/2017/tensor-decomposition-autograd.html for a numpy based solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 0):

Missing values are not yet supported in Tucker and CP decompositions. However, [robust tensor PCA](http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.decomposition.robust_pca.html#tensorly.decomposition.robust_pca) does and you can use it to recover the missing values, and separate low-rank part and sparse noise.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later. The rate of convergence of tensor decomposition is very slow. Will PCA 
 be faster？